# Executable file (GUI) - Can this exe use subprocess.run() to open a .py file in the same map? Not working

Tags: python, tkinter, python-os

I have a GUI.

Which works and opens .py file when I use it from Jupyter notebook.
But after creating a .exe file for it, it doesn't open the .py file when clicking the button.

Code within the GUI just looks like this:

```
def run():
    process = subprocess.run('python AutomationSPStoOBM.py ' + filename ,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True) # run the file
    if process.returncode != 0: # check if error happened
        error = process.stderr.decode() # grab the error
        messagebox.showinfo("Warning", error)  
    else:    
        label3 = Label(window)
        label3['text'] = 'Successfully created 1 OBM!'
        label3.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)


Button2 = Button(window, text='2. Create OBM!', fg='black', bg='white', height = 2, width = 39, command=run)
Button2.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
```

After converting this GUI to an executable, the 'Button2' doesn't open/run the .py file no more.

Any idea how I can open this 'AutomationSPStoOBM.py' within the executable?

Would Be really helpful!

UPDATE (first Issue was solved):
I now use a GUI that at some point imports a .py file:

```
def browse_files():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    filename = '\"' + filename + '\"'
    label2 = Label(window)
    label2['text'] = 'Unknown'
    if len(str(filename)) > 3:  
        label2['text'] = filename
    else:
        label2['text'] = 'You didn\'t upload any file yet.'

    label2.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

def run():
    import AutomationSPStoOBM
    label3 = Label(window)
    label3['text'] = 'Successfully created 1 OBM!'
    label3.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
```

In the .py file: AutomationSPStoOBM it inputs a file.
But this file I want to specify with the GUI in browse-files button. How can I give this string to the import AutomationSPStoOBM?

Comment: is this all your code? Did you run .exe in console/terminal to see all error messages?

Comment: why not use it in normal way - `import AutomationSPStoOBM` and run code from module - but it may need to put code in functions.

Comment: `.exe` may not give direct access to `python.exe` and it may need to use `/full/path/to/python /full/path/to/AutomationSPStoOBM.py` - problem can be that `.exe` can uncompress it to temporary folder with random name and you have to use special variables to access this folder - at least in `PyInstaller` (and this need to read documentation for `PyInstaller`)

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: import AutomationSPStoOBM, sounds interesting. What is this type of way called? I have never worked with it. Will I have to put the entire .py file in one function?

Comment: it is normal way to work with Python. For example when you do `import tkinter` then it loads code from file `tkinter.py` or folder `tkinter/`- and it searchs this file/folder using list `sys.path`. Eventaully it may need to add your folder to `sys.path` before `import`. But Python remebers imported file and it doesn't import it again - and it is better to keep code in function and do  `import AutomationSPStoOBM` and `AutomationSPStoOBM.your_function()`.

Comment: BTW: in question you should add information what tool you use to create `.exe` - ie. `PyInstaller`, `py2exe`, `cx_freeze`, etc. - because they may need different changes.

Comment: @furas I used your method and this is indeed way easier! - One problem I have is that first I used ''python AutomationSPStoOBM.py filename'''and then sys.argv[1] to get the right filename and run it. Now I don't know how to give my filename that I get from my GUI to the 'Import AutomationSPStoOBM'

Comment: @furas I edited my original question with an Update to show you exactly what I mean.